# In chef, how do I access attributes within role files?

Tags: chef

I'm able to set attributes in role files as [documented](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Roles) but I'm not able to access attributes already set by cookbooks that I'm using.

For example within /roles/appserver.rb:

```
name "appserver"

run_list(%w{
  recipe[tomcat::default]
})

default_attributes(
  :tomcat => {
    :java_options => "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=" + node[:tomcat][:log_dir]
  }
)
```

What I get is an exception stating chef can't find the 'node' method/variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot. The role [Ruby DSL](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Roles) is converted from Ruby to JSON when you upload the role to the server with knife. The node object is not available, since it is not processed in the context of a Chef run.

If you want to combine node attributes, instead, you should do that in a recipe, for example:

```
"#{node[:tomcat][:java_options]}#{node[:tomcat][:log_dir]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actualy use `require_relative 'base_role_file'` inside a role and this required file may set some global variables for you to use. Pretty hacky.